# Can an image be included in a webpage but protected from copying/saving?

Tags: javascript, image, dhtml

I have a website where I display digital proofs for clients of professional photographers.  I would like to include an option of 'zooming' into the full resolution version of the image, but it is absolutely imperative that it be practically impossible for the end user to reconstruct and save/print the image.

Obviously simply disabling right clicking is out, as the user could simply dig up the image in the cache.  Breaking the image into tiles, then reconstructing them via javascript has merit; the user could still dig up the tiles and put them together in Photoshop, but is that practical for them?  That's up for debate.  I was also wandering today if the image couldn't be read, sent as a character string of pixel color values, and then constructed on the client side using an absolutely positioned element for each pixel.

But my potential solutions seem to be getting more and more ridiculously convoluted.  And I'd like something that's been tested and shown to be scalable.  I can't possibly be the first to deal with this problem.  Is there something else out there that I don't know about?  What is the standard, accepted way to do this?

As an aside, I am aware that I will want to make the image data unavailable to external http requests.  I would plan to have ColdFusion read the image file on demand and stream it to the client.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to keep something from being copied on the internet, don't put it on the internet.

Comment: +1 for humorous. Not helpful, but nicely concise

Comment: zzzzBov, you have misread the question.  I was very careful to use the word 'practically'.  There is a very big difference between what is practical and impractical and what is possible and impossible.  In business, we are generally more concerned with the practical and probable than the possible.

Comment: Michael, thanks for the link; somehow I missed that in my search.

Comment: I've decided to use a number of the techniques I mentioned for now.  This includes a watermark, plus cutting the image into tiles.

Additionally, the full resolution tiles will only be downloaded and put together upon the user mousing over the thumbnail, then will disappear from the screen upon mousing out of the thumbnail.  I will also give the photographers the option of disabling this functionality.

That should meet my business needs.  Thanks, all, for the suggestions and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 100% reliability, no. For an image to be displayed, it has to be downloaded onto the client's browser, and therefore CAN be retrieved.

You can make it harder for them to extract the image through various techniques, but none of them make it impossible - if nothing else, they can always just make a screen capture:

1. slice/dice the image into multiple pices and use table-based layouts to make it appear as a single image
2. javascript right-click disablers
3. various cache headers to try and prevent client-side cacheing
4. CSS overlays to try and prevent right-click->save as on the image itself
5. display in a Flash/Java app
6. etc... etc...

None are 100% reliable, and are all trivial to bypass by a determined (and even slightly knowledgeable) user.

Comment: Many answers said the same thing, but this was the one that most addressed the issue of 'practical' over 'possible'.  I will likely use a minimal 'imprint' watermark along with tiled image 'pieces' with randomized filenames.

Answer (score 5):

No matter what you do, someone could always screen capture the page. Keep a watermark on the full resolution image.

Comment: That's exactly what I did when I made a photographer's gallery section. In fact, the actual full resolution image is never displayed, it is only available after purchase.

Comment: Thank you.  The images are already watermarked even at lower resolution.  But the more secure the watermark the more impact is stolen from the image.  So I would like to minimize watermark effect by employing other protection techniques as well.

Comment: As other commenters have pointed out, it is simply not possible to accomplish what you are attempting. Once it is on the internet, it will be stolen; even watermarks can be removed by a skilled and persistent thief.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't, unless you sell specific hardware, even then people can put a camera in front screen and take pictures
2. You can water mark your images
3. You can actively sue who ever steals your pictures (that is in reference to how others solve this).

Answer (score 0):

Nicholas,

As you pointed, there is no protection against Print Screen.
I would suggest you to implement the media protection of sites like Image Bank (http://www.gettyimages.com), but is mostly based in NOT displaying full resolution images and heavy watermarking ...
I don't think there is a practical solution to your problem (if any).
Good luck!